# ¿Cómo elimino un ciclo interior?

Tags: c++

¿Existe alguna función para eliminar el ciclo interior de la consola una vez terminada?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
cout << setiosflags( ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 4 );

float suma, prom, resultado;
int num = 1, y = 9, z = 10, w = 8, experimentos, NumResultados;

gotoxy( 5,7 );
cout << "Cuantos experimentos?: ";
cin >> experimentos;

do {
  gotoxy( 5, w );
  cout << "Cuantos resultados para este experimento?: ";
  cin >> NumResultados;
  for( int i = 1; i <= NumResultados; i++ ){
    gotoxy( 5, y );
    cout << "Ingrese los resultados para el experimento " << num << ": ";
    cin >> resultado;
    suma = resultado+suma;
  }
  prom = suma / NumResultados;
  gotoxy( 5, y );
  gotoxy( 5, z );
  cout << "Promedio " << num << ": " << prom;
  y = y + 3;
  num++;
  suma = 0;
  z = z + 3;
  w = w + 3;
} while( num <= experimentos);
```

Comment: Solo tienes 2 ciclos: el exterior, `do ... while`, y el interior, `for( )`. Tienes que quitar el `for( )`.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de que esto sea una pregunta sobre programacion ... yo diría que no ...

Answer (score -2):

Intenta usar `break();` o `return` en el bloque de código que quieres que se detenga al cumplirse determinada condición.